# How to find the volatility indices corresponding to equity indices?

Tags: volatility, equities, implied-volatility

I have a list of equity indices that I got through Eikon API (with Python). I successfully got their time series but at this point I would need the corresponding implied volatility, which is not available in Eikon for equity indices. How can I get it? Alternatively, how can I get the corresponding volatility index (if any)? For example, for the STOXX index there is the VIX index which tracks its implied volatility.

I know I could use Black and Scholes' model and find out the implied volatility in this way; however, I can't get the list of options associated with an equity index (and in any case it would be a much more tedious operation)

Comment: If you can't get information about the options associated to an index, then you probably can't compute the implied volatility (at least not according to the standard definition of implied volatility which relies heavily on inputs from the options).